# How to import a custom folder to my project with SBT in Play! Framework compile and run task?

Tags: java, git, playframework, sbt

I have two different repositories, one with the backend written in Java Play! Framework and the other with the frontend HTML, CSS and JS code. As the frontend is reused in different platforms is a git repository itself and the backend is another. We are now copy-pasting the frontend each time a new change on it is made so as to keep track of it on the backend. 
We want to do the following tasks at compile and run time of the Play! Framework project:

1. checkout the frontend repository to a certain branch
2. copy the code in a certain relative path to the backend public folder.
3. compile / run or stage the application.

Is it possible to configure this steps in sbt of the backend project? If so, how can I do it?

I'm using Play! Framework 2.2.4 with Java on Windows and Linux. There is a basepath like:

- /XX/develop/frontEnd  <-- Frontend project
- /XX/develop/backEnd   <-- Backend project

Comment: I think that what you want is a multi project application: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTSubProjects

Comment: It could work. I´ll check.Thanks!